# How using same url but different controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have one problem is how to use the same url but different controller, I've tried

```
$router->get('/{slug}', 'ProductCategoryController@_handle')->name('productcategory');
$router->get('/{slug?}', 'PageController@_handle')->name('page');
```

When used I did it out like this

```
URL::route('productcategory', $slug)
URL::route('page', $slug)
```

But by default it only works from the top down and only uses the first url. So I want to ask how it can be used separately url.

Hope everyone will help me and I am very thankful for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Laravel has any built-in solution for it but you can it as:

```
$router->get('/{slug?}', function($slug = null) {
    if (is_null($slug)) {
        retrun app('App\Http\Controllers\PageController')->_handle();
    } esle {
        retrun app('App\Http\Controllers\ProductCategoryController')->_handle($slug);
    }
});
```